# Which variation of C++ Operator Overloading should I use? And, why?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Here 3 variations of the overloading of addition operator (+) are given.

Which variation should I use and why?

```
class MyClass {
    int myInteger;
    double myDouble;
    public:
        MyClass(int i, double d) {
        myInteger = i;
        myDouble = d;
    }

    // Variation - 1
    //--------------
    MyClass operator +(MyClass rhsObj) {
        return MyClass(this->myInteger + rhsObj.myInteger, this->myDouble + rhsObj.myDouble);
    }

    // Variation - 2
    //--------------
    MyClass &operator +(MyClass &rhsObj) {
        rhsObj.myInteger = this->myInteger + rhsObj.myInteger;
        rhsObj.myDouble = this->myDouble + rhsObj.myDouble;

        return rhsObj;
    }

    // Variation - 3
    //--------------    
    MyClass &operator +(MyClass &rhsObj) {
        this->myInteger = this->myInteger + rhsObj.myInteger;
        this->myDouble = this->myDouble + rhsObj.myDouble;

        return *this;
    }
};


int main() {
    MyClass objOne(10, 10.5);
    MyClass objTwo(20, 20.5);

    MyClass objThree = objOne + objTwo;
}
```

What should be the case of Assignment Operator (=)? Which variation should it use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really want variations on *one* and *three* here.

Users of `MyClass` will expect it to follow [The Principle of Least Astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) and would never expect to see the right-hand-side modified as a result of addition. Using `const` more will enforce this and will also serve as documentation. If you wish to modify the left-hand-side, use `+=`. Like so:

```
// Plus: Modify neither the left nor the right
//--------------
MyClass operator +(const MyClass& rhsObj) const
{
    return MyClass(myInteger + rhsObj.myInteger, myDouble + rhsObj.myDouble);
}

// Increment: Modify the left
//--------------
MyClass& operator +=(const MyClass& rhsObj)
{
    myInteger += rhsObj.myInteger;
    myDouble += rhsObj.myDouble;

    return *this;
}
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/8oarA

Answer (score 10):

Depends on what you need.

First, about you versions - obviously

- "Variation - 1" creates new object, without touching the two operands.
- "Variation - 2" stores the result in the second operand
- "Variation - 3" stores the result in the first operand in "this".

---

Most likely, Variation - 1 is the most preferred.

Why? Because of the side effects. If you see an expression like:

```
a = b + c;
```

whatever is the type of `a`, `b` and `c`, what you would think? I would think, that `a` is the sum of `b` and `c` AND `b` and `c` are untouched, I mean - with the old values.
Suppose, for example:

```
a = 5;
b = 6;
c = a + b;
```

Would you expect, that `a` or `b` will become `11` after the sum? (which will happen if you chose variation 2 or 3). Of course, you **cannot** overload `operator+` for `int`, but it's just an easy and intuitive example.

---

One performance improvement: in your variation 1, instead of

```
MyClass operator+(MyClass rhsObj)
```

I would use

```
MyClass operator+(const MyClass& rhsObj)
```

This way you'll avoid one additional copy + you will tell the "client", using your code, that you don't change `rhsObj` at all, but just use its value.

Comment: What should be the case of Assignment Operator (=)? Which variation should it use?

Comment: How many variations you think it can has? Also, it's another question.

Comment: @Saqib: None! For Assignment You should use the [Copy and Swap idiom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom)

Answer (score 4):

There are subtle differences between these three `+`'s

The first variation:

```
// Variation - 1
//--------------
MyClass operator+(MyClass rhsObj)
{
    return MyClass(this->myInteger + rhsObj.myInteger, this->myDouble + rhsObj.myDouble);
}
```

takes an object of `MyClass` as input, which means a copy of `rhsObj` is passed into the `+` remaining the original object `rhsObj` unchanged. This override returns a newly created object of `MyClass`.

The second variation:

```
// Variation - 2
//--------------
MyClass & operator+(MyClass & rhsObj)
{
    rhsObj.myInteger = this->myInteger + rhsObj.myInteger;
    rhsObj.myDouble = this->myDouble + rhsObj.myDouble;

    return rhsObj;
}
```

takes a reference to `rhsObj` as input and the `rhsObj` is updated in the method.

The last variation

```
// Variation - 3
//--------------    
MyClass & operator+(MyClass & rhsObj)
{
    this->myInteger = this->myInteger + rhsObj.myInteger;
    this->myDouble = this->myDouble + rhsObj.myDouble;

    return *this;
}
```

also takes a reference to `rhsObj` as parameter, but `rhsObj` is not modified inside the method. Instead, the `MyClass` object on which the `+` is invoked updated.

Comment: @Saqib You can use variation1 if you don't want the orginal object updated or variation3.

Answer (score 2):

Conceptually, you want to return a new pair, so in your case the first variant is perhaps better.

Or perhaps you want to return one of the argument, but then I find confusing the name of the operator. It could be better `+=` for the third variant.

Comment: What should be the case of Assignment Operator (=)? Which variation should it use?

Comment: `+=` is usually perceived as an assignment operator.

Comment: Copy Assignment Operator is `=` not `+=`.

Answer (score 0):

I would think variation 1 would be best for mainly one reason: if you had just the statement `lhs + rhs;`, would you expect/want `lhs` or `rhs` to be modified? I know that I probably wouldn't in most (all?) cases.

Therefore that rules out variations 2 and 3.

Comment: What should be the case of Assignment Operator (=)? Which variation should it use?